[Running cypress on Jenkins]: Missing X server or $DISPLAY, The platform failed to initialize
So, let me first give the entire context out here:
-> We are having cypress UI end2end test suite that we want to run every night as part of our Jenkins nightly build. We are running the cypress tests in headless mode, but have passed the --record tag so that we get the video recording saved to our dashboard.
-> As part of a step in our jenkins pipeline, we are running the cypress test inside a docker image.
Here is the cypress_run.sh file that is used as a starting point to run the test within jenkins:
# Update package list
apt-get update

apt-get install apache2

# Install NVM (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

# Load NVM
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# Use NVM to install the specified version of Node.js
nvm install 20

# Use npm to install the specified version of npm
npm install -g npm@9

# Display versions for verification
echo "NVM version: \$(nvm --version), Node version: \$(node --version), npm version: \$(npm --version)"

apt-get update

apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb

echo "Running Cypress Command"
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
# Install Xvfb
apt-get install -y xvfb

# Start Xvfb
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# Set the display environment variable
export DISPLAY=:99
echo "Installed NPM Packages!"
export CYPRESS_BASE_URL="$UNIFIED_URL"
export CYPRESS_USERNAME="admin"
export CYPRESS_PASSWORD="password"
echo "Cypress base Url: ${CYPRESS_BASE_URL}"
npx cypress run --record --key <KEY> --browser chrome --headless --config-file cypress.config.js --config baseUrl="$CYPRESS_BASE_URL" username="$CYPRESS_USERNAME" password="$CYPRESS_PASSWORD"

Now, this code entire setup runs fine majority of the time, but once in a while it starts throwing the following error on jenkins, and then there is no way I can solve that:
[2024-04-01T18:58:54.001Z] Cypress base Url: https://mondaytestingcypress.jfrogdev.org

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.001Z] [STARTED] Task without title.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] Cypress failed to start.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] ----------

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.559Z] [FAILED] [1606:0401/185854.356170:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] [1606:0401/185854.356223:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] ----------

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.8)

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [FAILED] Cypress Version: 12.17.4

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] Cypress failed to start.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] Please refer to the error below for more details.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] ----------

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [1606:0401/185854.356170:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] [1606:0401/185854.356223:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] ----------

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] 

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] Platform: linux-x64 (Debian - 11.8)

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] Cypress Version: 12.17.4

[2024-04-01T18:58:54.560Z] ./cypress_run.sh: line 44:  1582 Aborted                 (core dumped) Xvfb :"$RANDOM_DISPLAY_PORT_NUMBER" -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1

I have tried multiple approaches, which temporarily solves the problem, but when it appears again, it fails all the subsequent jenkins builds.
-> I have manually hardcoded a different display port number, let's say 100, this solved the problem for a limited time, but started failing the builds again.
Xvfb :100 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# Set the display environment variable
export DISPLAY=:100

So, I assumed that the PORT number might be the issue. So, at each build, I was generating a random number within a given range and assigned the PORT to that number.
RANDOM_DISPLAY_PORT_NUMBER=$(shuf -i 10-98 -n 1)

# Start Xvfb
Xvfb :"$RANDOM_DISPLAY_PORT_NUMBER" -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# Set the display environment variable
export DISPLAY=":$RANDOM_DISPLAY_PORT_NUMBER"
echo "DISPLAY PORT NUMBER SELECTED IS: $RANDOM_DISPLAY_PORT_NUMBER"

This fixed the problem for a long time, I wasn't getting that issue for a week then, but again the builds have started failing again. Now matter how many times I manually trigger the builds, I get the same error message every time.

I think cypress will disregard your DISPLAY variable unless you prefix it with CYPRESS_ -- see cypress environment variables docs for more info. Although, I would not have expected xvfb to be needed at all when running a headless browser. Have you tried rebooting the Jenkins node?

Cypress will disregard your DISPLAY variable (and any other environment variable) unless you prefix it with CYPRESS_ -- see cypress environment variables docs which states in relevant part:

Any exported environment variables set on the command line or in your CI provider that start with either CYPRESS_ or cypress_ will automatically be parsed by Cypress.

This statement might also be understood by inverse reasoning to mean: any variable not prefixed with CYPRESS_ will not be parsed by Cypress.
You can also use any of the other methods for setting variables with Cypress.

Thanks a lot for the answer, I tried that changing the DISPLAY variable to CYPRESS_DISPLAY and it seems to solve my problem for the moment. Also, I had earlier tried rebooting the jenkins node, that did not help. Since the variable change worked for me currently, but how do I confirm that this is the final solution. (Asking this because there have been multiple solutions that I have tried earlier, they used to solve my problem temporarily)

re-ran the pipeline multiple times, and now I can see the problem coming back again!
Do you recommend changing anything in the cypress_run.sh file?
